# When is a local static variable stored in memory?

Tags: c

At what point does the language require the compiler to store a local static variable into memory? Is it at compile time? Or at runtime when the function that contains the local static variable is called?

```
int* GetMyVariable()
{
    static int A = 50;
    return &A;
}
```

I want to be able to only use memory for 'A' if GetMyVariable() is called. If static doesn't work like this, then is a dynamic allocation my only option? Thanks for your time.

Comment: storage is allocated for that at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When is a local static variable stored in memory

This is done prior to the execution of the program.

> (C99, 6.2.4p3) "An object whose identifier is declared with external
>           or internal linkage, or with the storage-class specifier static
>           has static storage duration. Its lifetime is the entire execution
>           of the program and its stored value is initialized only once,
>           prior to program startup."

Answer (score 1):

A static variable in C exists throughout the whole execution of a program. Therefore, you can safely take the address of that variable at any time.